# How long does it take for SharePoint Online permission changes to propagate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups, sharepoint-permissions

I had, I thought, removed a user from an MS 365 group that is a member of a SharePoint group on a SharePoint Online site, but they still appear to be in the group when doing Check Permissions. How long should it be before the change propagates? I made the change a yesterday or the day before, but they still appear to be members of the SharePoint Group. I have tried getting a PowerShell script iteratively to display the end users of the member groups, but without success so far.

SP Group -> MS 365 Group -> Users

It would be really great if one could run a script or drill down to display the end users of the various groups. Instead, you stop at the group and there isn't a link to display the users.

Comment: Hi Stephen. Just curious. After waiting for 2 days, did you get the permissions propagated to SharePoint already?

Comment: Still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an update? PowerShell to Get SharePoint Online Group members with SharePoint Online Management Shell:

```
#Config Variables
$AdminCenterURL = "https://crescenttech-admin.sharepoint.com/"
$SiteURL="https://crescenttech.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing"
$GroupName= "Team Site Members"
 
#Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-SPOService -url $AdminCenterURL -Credential (Get-Credential)
   
#sharepoint online powershell get group members
Get-SPOUser -Site $SiteURL -Group $GroupName
```

Reference:
[SharePoint Online: PowerShell to Get Group Members](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/03/sharepoint-online-get-groups-using-powershell.html)

Comment: I used a similar script before. It just shows the first-level group members, i.e. other groups; it does not recursively list group members; I want to drill down to show the members of the groups that are members of that group. Check Permissions seems to indicate membership, but when I look at the individual groups, that membership is missing, it seems.